# what are all possible filters to add to a server-side trace?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, monitoring, trace

[On this question you can see how to set up a filter on your trace.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20159/setting-up-filtering-for-server-side-tracing)

this code below filters a trace file to capture only events that happen on database 'AdventureWorks'

```
-- Set the Filters
declare @intfilter int
declare @bigintfilter bigint

set @bigintfilter = 1000000
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 13, 0, 4, @bigintfilter

exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 35, 0, 6, N'AdventureWorks'

-- Set the trace status to start
exec sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 1
```

from the example above:

1) what is 13?

2) I know that 35 must be database Name.

How can I find what could be the other options (hostname, program, ObjectName, etc?) where are them stored? which system table or view?

[Here you can see what filters you have on your trace.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173838.aspx)

I found this link helpful:
[Need sp_trace_setfilter xref list of @columnid parameters](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic279642-5-1.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from this question: [Find out what columns are in a trace file](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114446/find-out-what-columns-are-in-a-trace-file)

there is this script

```
--  Gets all Events for a given trace id
SELECT a.[EventID], b.[name] AS [Even Name], a.[ColumnID], c.[name] AS [Column Name], d.[name] AS [Category]
FROM fn_trace_geteventinfo(<trace ID>) AS a --<<Put the trace ID you are interested in
    INNER JOIN sys.trace_events AS b ON a.EventID = b.Trace_Event_ID
    INNER JOIN sys.trace_columns AS c ON a.ColumnID = c.Trace_Column_ID
    INNER JOIN sys.trace_categories AS d ON b.Category_ID = d.Category_ID
ORDER BY a.[EventID], a.[ColumnID]
```

that shows all the columns of a trace, due to the DMV [sys.trace_columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180067.aspx)

[image]

I have put in place a server side trace with the following filters:
(this is part of the script)

```
-- Set the Filters
declare @intfilter int
declare @bigintfilter bigint

exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 10, 0, 7, N'SQL Server Profiler - 53e0541a-7b74-4fce-bcac-9255e79a6372'
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 34, 1, 6, N'udpProductTaxRateGet'
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 34, 1, 6, N'udpProductBulletPointSelectByTier1NoteTypeCode'
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 35, 1, 6, N'US16AUTPProduct'
-- Set the trace status to start
exec sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 1

-- display trace id for future references
select TraceID=@TraceID
```

When I run this query now, I can see what columns are there, and exactly how the filters would work.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
-- what filters are set on @traceid
-- and how they are working
-- marcelo miorelli sql server 2005 - 8-8-2016
------------------------------------------------------------
declare @traceid int
select @traceid = 2
select a.[columnid]

     ,c.[type_name]
     ,c.[name] as [Column Name]

     ,[ @comparison_operator ] = CASE A.comparison_operator 
                                     WHEN 0 THEN '= (Equal)'
                                     WHEN 1 THEN '<> (Not Equal)'
                                     WHEN 2 THEN '> (Greater Than)'
                                     WHEN 3 THEN '< (Less Than)'
                                     WHEN 4 THEN '>= (Greater Than Or Equal)'
                                     WHEN 5 THEN '<= (Less Than Or Equal)'
                                     WHEN 6 THEN 'LIKE'
                                     WHEN 7 THEN 'NOT LIKE'
                                     ELSE 'NOT SURE'
                               END
     ,a.value
     ,[ @logical_operator ]    = CASE A.LOGICAL_OPERATOR 
                                     WHEN  1 THEN 'OR'  
                                     ELSE         'AND' 
                                 END
 from fn_trace_getfilterinfo( @traceid ) a
    INNER JOIN sys.trace_columns AS c ON a.ColumnID = c.Trace_Column_ID
```

[image]

> --[ @logical_operator = ] logical_operator
>
> --Specifies whether the AND (0) or OR (1) operator is applied.
>
> --logical_operator is int, with no default.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186265.aspx) article gives all the filter arguments and available columns including the code.

I use it often as a reference to create server-side traces.

Answer (score 1):

First of all remember that traces and profiler have been deprecated and you should really be looking at Extended Events.  None of the information you are looking for is in system views (that I know of) but it is in `Books on Line`.  First look at the format of [sp_trace_setfilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174404.aspx)

> sp_trace_setfilter [ @traceid = ] trace_id
>             , [ @columnid = ] column_id
>             , [ @logical_operator = ] logical_operator
>             , [ @comparison_operator = ] comparison_operator
>             , [ @value = ] value

The `@columnid` column is the one you are concerned with but you also want to look at the `@logical_operator` and the `@comparison_operator`.

The information on the `@columnid`s possible is found in the BOL entry for [sp_trace_setevent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186265.aspx).

> sp_trace_setevent [ @traceid = ] trace_id
>             , [ @eventid = ] event_id
>             , [ @columnid = ] column_id
>             , [ @on = ] on

There is a whole tables of possible `@eventid`s and `@columnid`s (what you are looking for).

Here is a brief example of some of the data in the `@columnid` table including #13:

[image]

Comment: very good point, I still cannot think "extended events" when under a stress situation - I can only think "server side trace".

Comment: And there's no reason you shouldn't. Deprecated does not mean irrelevant or useless. I can't say I prefer Extended Events for this having practiced the painful art of Server Side tracing for so long!

Comment: @Molenpad It's more a matter of practicing for the future. I've got a large group of people who use DTS packages that are about to be in a world of hurt when 2008 R2 goes out of service.

Comment: @Kenneth Fisher, I'm with you there. Ouch.